# Passing an object to a different controller than it's own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, controller

I am trying to pass an object to another controller, so that I can sort based on this object. dgroups has_many plans.  I am trying to sort my plans based on dgroup.id   I have the following code

dgroups view:

```
    <% @dgroup.each do |dgroup| %>
<tr>
<td><%= dgroup.dings.map(&:id) %></td>
<td><%= dgroup.id %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show Plans', plans_path %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dgroup_path(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dgroup, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

plans controller:

```
    def index
     @dID = Dgroup.find(params[:id])
     @plans = @dID.plans
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @plans }
    end
 end
```

I've tried passing diaggroup from the dgroups view, like:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Plans', plans_path(dgroup) %></td>
```

But this did not work.  I am not sure why, the errors I was getting made it seem like the controller was assuming I was sending a plan.  Any suggestions?  I'm really new to ruby so I'm curious how methods on various controllers are supposed to be called.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you want is this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Plans', plans_path(:id => dgroup.id) %></td>
```

If it doesn't work try to change the parameter name like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Plans', plans_path(:dgroup_id => dgroup.id) %></td>
```

and in your controller:

```
@dID = Dgroup.find(params[:dgroup_id])
```

Comment: The second two lines worked, the first line did not.  Why does the second line work, what exactly is it doing? Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a good place to use nested resources?

```
resources :dgroups do
  resources :plans do
  end
end

rake routes
    dgroup_plans GET    /dgroups/:dgroup_id/plans(.:format)          plans#index
...
    dgroup_plan GET    /dgroups/:dgroup_id/plans/:id(.:format)       plans#show

<td><%= link_to 'Show Plans', dgroup_plans(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit Plan', dgroup_plan(dgroup, plan) %></td>
```

Comment: where do you add the resources lines?

Comment: nvm, it goes in routes.rb, my bad.  but when does this mean i always have to include a dgroup object when calling the controller?

Comment: Right, you will have to include dgroup_id every time you want to access plans, it's how nested resources work.